# SSRS Report Designer background image resolution issue

Tags: sql, visual-studio, reporting-services

Ever since upgrading to VS 2019 I have issues with the SQL Server Data Tools Report Designer and background images. My report is tabloid 11x17 and I have a rectangle that is filled with an embedded image that is 10.5 x 17 at 96 DPI. When I export the report page to PDF it looks perfect however in the report designer you can see how it's sized (causing additional development pain). Does anyone have any tips? It's like VS is expecting a 120 DPI image.

I have tried changing the DPI settings in VS and the display settings on my machine in case this is a high dpi issue. Many thanks. [Screenshot of my page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AIymf.jpg)

Comment: I've noticed that BMP images display better than PNG or JPGs. It's also best to use CLIP rather than FIT to keep the original resolution. Not sure what the actual issue is - you say it looks perfect in PDF.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, the clip option works fine by issue is with the Report Designer it doesn't show the background image in it's full resolution so its trial and error designing the report content (tablix, text box etc) in the proper place over the background image. If I set the bg image to 120dpi it fits perfectly in the designer but then the export to PDF  causes bleedovers because the image is too big.

Comment: In case anyone else is struggling with this the workaround I found was to set my Windows Display Settings scale to 100% -- then open VS -- then set the Display scale back to what you need it at. None of the DPI optimization settings I tried in VS corrected the issue.